# Smarty generate script tag with empty src

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6, w3c-validation

i am using PrestaShop e-commerce [electromarket theme](https://prestasites.com/theme/electromarket)

this is smarty code that generate js header file

```
   {if isset($js_defer) && !$js_defer && isset($js_files) && isset($js_def)}
    {$js_def}
    {foreach from=$js_files item=js_uri}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$js_uri|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"></script>
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

but in rendered HTML it generate script tag without any src

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="" ></script>
```

When I use w3 validator it gives me the error:

[image: w3 validator error]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add another condition

```
{if isset($js_defer) && !$js_defer && isset($js_files) && isset($js_def)}
   {$js_def}
   {foreach from=$js_files item=js_uri}
       {if $js_uri}
           <script type="text/javascript" src="{$js_uri|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"></script>
       {/if}
   {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: You have to clear PrestaShop and browser cache.
also change {if $js_uri} to  {if file_exists($js_uri)} for more certainty